# A sequence of Riemann integrable function.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{r_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ and let

$$
f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}\; x\in\{r_1,\dots, r_n\} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

I must be prove that $f_n$ is Riemann Integrable for all $n$ and the Rimann Integral is zero.

Now, since the set of discontinuity point of $f_n$ is finite, results that $f_n$ is Riemann integrable.

How can I prove that the Riemann integral is zero? Can we show that fn is Riemann integrable using the definition? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For any partition, $P$, of $[0,1]$, it is clear that
$$L(f_{n}, P, [0,1]) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_{j}-x_{j-1})\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_{j}]} f_{n} = 0$$
If $f_{n}$ is Reimann integrable, then the integral will be $0$ as $\sup_{P} L(f_{n},P,[0,1]) = 0$.

For any $\varepsilon > 0$. Let $\delta = \min\{\min_{i,j\leq n, i\neq j}|r_{i}-r_{j}|, \varepsilon\}$. Choose $P_{\varepsilon}$ to be a partition that partitions $[0,1]$ into intervals of length $\delta/n$. We then have that
$$|U(f_{n}, P_{\varepsilon}, [0,1]) - L(f_{n},P_{\varepsilon},[0,1])| = U(f_{n},P_{\varepsilon}, [0,1]) = n \cdot \delta/n = \delta \leq \varepsilon$$
Hence, $f_{n}$ is Reimann integrable if you want to prove it using the definition.

Comment: Thanks. A last question: why in this way $\sup_{[x_{j-1}-x_j]}f_n=1$?

Comment: As we partition $[0,1]$ to intervals of length $\delta/n$ (where $\delta$ is defined above), there are precisely $n$ intervals where there exists a singular $r_{i}$ for each of those intervals such that $f_{n}(r_{i}) = 1$. In those $n$ intervals, $\sup_{[x_{j-1},x_{j}]}f_{n} = 1$.  There are $n$ cases where $\sup_{[x_{j-1},x_{j}]}f_{n} = 1$ instead of $0$, and the length of each interval is $\delta/n$, hence, $U(f_{n}, P_{\varepsilon}, [0,1]) = n \cdot \delta/n$.

Comment: So the letter $n$ that appears in the sums is the same to the $n$ of the sequence?

Comment: Yes. The $n$ in the proof and everywhere you see it corresponds to $f_{n}$.